# Benefits of updating the ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates

i am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS .What are the benefits of updating by update manager ?

Answer (score 0):

The benefits include

1. security fixes (most important)
2. bug fixes
3. functionality and UI (user interface) improvements to existing
   packages you have installed
4. access to new packages

You should, as a general rule, always keep your system up to date in order for it to function smoothly and securely.

Comment: How would using the GUI differ in end results from `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`? Aren't the end results identical?

Comment: @Marc the GUI will do the equivalent of apt-get dist-upgrade which will upgrade kernel etc. along with packages.